How can I increase the volume of this video intercom device?
I recently moved and the video intercom device is faulty. Given building conditions a repair cannot be performed and my device rings and sounds at a very low volume. I have to be at a meter's distance to hear the ring.
I was wondering if I could very cheaply hack the device so that the volume is louder. Perhaps connecting a different buzzer that has external power? I'm a bit of a noob and I'm just trying to find some solution to this problem.
Here's the device and its connections.



I've not been lucky in finding the manual for this specific device. Any pointers and any general information on how such devices work would be appreciated.

The intercom PDF: https://auta.es/wp-content/uploads/MONITOR-DECOR-ANALOGICO_ES_EN-HI-861.pdf
EDIT: This is not digital but the model similar to yours.
The wall connector PDF (not exactly the same one): https://auta.es/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/MODULO-CONEXION-COMPACT-ANALOGICO-HI-133.pdf
EDIT: The most accurate wall module is this one: https://auta.es/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/M%C3%B3dulo-CONEXI%C3%93N-COMPACT-COAXIAL_ES_IN_PT_FR-HI-762-1.pdf
Connect the 24v buzzer as shown in the image.
Cheers.


Worked flawlessly. Thanks. Good luck in your travels.

Awesome, take care GG.

The manual (p10) shows a well-hidden button to set the volume to high or low.  Underneath the ear end of the handset are two holes between the hook and a circular speaker grille.  The one on the left changes the volume between high and low.  The one on the right changes the ringtone; you may be able to set something more obvious.
The system allows an extra phone to be connected to the right-hand block of screw terminals, suggesting that should ring.  But that's probably a handset from the same manufacturer, not something easy to buy
While there are terminals for an external speaker and "call extension" the manual lacks information on how you'd use them.  First I'd try a voltmeter on AC volts mode between the rightmost (negative) terminal and the speaker terminal (4th from the right)  and get someone to ring the bell.  If it did anything I'd look at wiring a small speaker there directly, but I have a collection of scrap electronics.  A DC signal voltage used to signal an accessory unit is also a possibility.

It's possible there's some damage to the buzzer/chime, like corrosion (but I'm just spitballing here).

I've got a small 24V siren, I think it should be possible to wire it to those connectors on the right side. I've measured 24V when connecting to the rightmost connector (-) and the 4th from the right speaker connector. Problem is those are always live. I wonder if the 2C and AUX slots might be meaningful here.

https://auta.es/wp-content/uploads/MONITOR-DECOR-ANALOGICO_ES_EN-HI-861.pdf
Also found this manual which is more accurate, less information though.

My dad's hearing has gotten bad, so when he's downstairs he doesn't hear the doorbell chime (which is located in the kitchen on the floor above).  I got my parents a doorbell extender, which consists of a battery-op transmitter and a plug-in receiver.  The Tx sits on top of the doorbell chime in the kitchen, and the Rx plugs into the wall downstairs.  When someone rings the bell, there's a chime from the Rx downstairs.
Perhaps something like that could work for you.  I don't remember what I bought for my parents, but this is an example of a similar device: https://heath-zenith.com/products/doorbell-extender-kit

To be clear, does this need wiring in or does it pick up on the audio from the existing bell to trigger  it?  The latter would be handy if it's sensitive enough (which it might not be) as there's no need to consider voltage compatibility.

No wiring involved.  I believe it picks up the audio from the existing chime.
